# One network adaptor, one network. Two gateways, two internet connections

Tags: networking, adapter

- My network has two modems/gateways, each connected to a different ISP on a different line.
- My computer has one network adapter.
- Just to make sure everything is clear, this is all set up on one network, where every device can communicate with all others.

By setting up static routing i can easily chose which internet connection i want to use.
Now, I want to use both internet connections simultaneously, such that each program uses a different connection. I have tried:

- Creating a virtual adapter with windows loopback adapter, configure it to use a different gateway than the physical adapter and use ForceBindIP to launch each program. But I could not get this to work (probably because there is no connection between the virtual adapter and the network?). I tried to create a network bridge between the two adapters (physical and virtual) but windows forces them to use the same gateway and i want each to use a different gateway.
- Desperately trying to use virtualbox network adapter to somehow do the trick. But i dont know how to do this. If i create a virtual machine with "bridged connection" i can configure the VM to use one gateway while the host OS uses the other gateway. But i dont want to use VMs, I want the host OS to use both gateways.

How can I use one network adapter to connect to two different gateways and then chose which programs use which gateway?

Thank you very much!

Comment: just wondering if you ever got this setup to work?

Answer (score 3):

I've mucked around with this. I simply had one system connect to both gateways (with different ip address ranges), and used a load balancing proxy.

[Connectify dispatch](http://www.connectify.me/dispatch/) does this for you VERY simply , has a free version, and a paid version with more features.

An alternative a free open-source alternative called [dispatch-proxy](https://github.com/Morhaus/dispatch-proxy) that works well enough for me. It lacks most of the bells and whistles, but its free, and will work with any software that allows for a proxy server. I've run this with two wireless connections on different subnets and it seems to work as it should. Its a little complex (needs node.js) and lacks some features dispatch has.

In this case, I'd run one instance per connection profile you want for maximum flexibility. I suppose in theory, if you didn't want very finegrained control and went the proxy route, you could run a small proxy bound to the ip address you want to use, and do the same.

A third alternative might be to simply buy a dual WAN router, and have it as a single gateway.

Comment: Could you share a link on how to get this to work in Connectify/Speedify? I have not been able to find out how to get it setup for the given scenario, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, you won't be able to do this on a per program basis from Windows unless it is a special program that does something which allows you to select the interface (e.g. wireshark).

The reason for this, most applications that use networking on Windows simply use abstractions/shared libraries and are not aware of the physical network - the application simply makes an outbound request to a hostname or ip address.

Now, if you had only a few applications and you know exactly what they are doing and what sites they are accessing, what you can do is set up a default gateway of the most used gateway and manually inject routes over the other one.

For example, router a's ip is 192.168.0.1, router b is 192.168.0.2.

If I want all my internet to go over router a, I would set that up as my default gateway. Next, if I wanted 8.8.8.8 to go over router b, I will then add a /32 static route for it. For example, on Windows:

```
route add 8.8.8.8 192.168.0.2
```

(Just learnt today, for /32, no need to define subnet).

This will force 8.8.8.8 to go via the second gateway whilst everything else goes over router A.

You are however giving yourself a management nightmare and I highly recommend you buy a load balancing router.